# Issue With "<" and ">" symbols

Tags: java, android

I am trying to say that if the number in the text box reaches over 10, then the text changes. However, Eclipse doesn't like the `>` symbol. What am I doing wrong?

```
if ( v == txtCarsInCarPark){
    txtCarsInCarPark = > 10;
    txtCarsInCarPark.setText("Car park Full");
}
```

Also, it seems to do the same here. However, this time I am trying to disable a button when the text box reaches under 0. Again, it doesn't like the `<` symbol.

```
if ( v == txtCarsInCarPark){
    txtCarsInCarPark = < 0;
    btnCarOut.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: This isn't how it's done in java. Also, if v is a `View`, compare using the View's ID instead since `==` is for comparing references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for an if statement is:

```
if (x >= 10)
{
     // do something
}
```

In your case, you first need to convert the string in the text box to integer:

```
num = Integer.parseInt(txtCarsInCarPark.getText().toString());
if (num >= 10)
    txtCarsInCarPark.setText("Car park Full");
```

Comment: This Did the Trick thanks, also thanks to everyone else who posted

Answer (score 1):

You inverted the order of the symbols, and added spaces between them, causing syntax errors. The correct syntax:

```
>=
```

and

```
<=
```

And, of course, that should go inside your conditions, not outside:

```
if(v == txtCarsInCarPark && txtCarsInCarPark >= 10) {
    // stuff...
}
```

(Assuming you want both conditions to match: `v` must be equal to `txtCarsInCarPark`, and they should be at least `10`).

Answer (score 0):

It should be >= not => switch your operators around and it will work

Answer (score 0):

try >= and <= also **no spaces**

Answer (score 0):

Please use >= and <= instead

Answer (score 0):

what is the variable "**v**" in your code?

If you want to justcheck the value of txtCarsInCarPark then put that in the brackets after the **if**:

```
if (txtCarsInCarPark >= 10){
    txtCarsInCarPark.setText("Car park Full");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

txtCarsInCarPark what is the datatype of this one?

you might have to use compareTo() if it is String or an object